# Why doesn't ajax form send it?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am making a ajax form. I get the success message but I dont get any email, any thoughts?

send-form.php:

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['email'])) ) {


  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

  //send email
  mail( "mymail@email.com", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['text'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] );

}
?>
```

functions.js:

```
$(function() {
  // Contact Form
$("#contact").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var text = $("#text").val();
  var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&text=' + text;
  $("#contact").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send-form.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
      $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    });
  }
 })
  return false;
});

});
```

index.html:

```
<form id="contact" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Your Name</label><br />
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text">  
    <label>Your Email</label><br />
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text">  
    <label>Your Question</label><br />
    <textarea rows="10" name="text" id="text" ></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit">
  <p class="success" style="display:none">Your message has been sent successfully.</p>
  <p class="error" style="display:none">E-mail must be valid and message must be longer than 100 characters.</p>
</form>
```

I have been siting with this in hours, trying to edit it with my own skill, but no success. This is what I got so far. I am getting the success message but no email sent to me.

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: I found all the info att https://spruce.it/noise/simple-ajax-contact-form/

Comment: Are you sure email is working on your server at all? are you sure `if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {` isn't causing it to exit?

Comment: What are the last errors in the server log?

Comment: "I don't get any email" covers a *very* wide range of potential problems.  Does the server respond as expected to the AJAX call?  Are there any server-side errors in the logs?  Is the `mail()` call being reached?  Is it returning successfully?  (Hint: You currently don't check for that.)  Is the SMTP server responding successfully?  Is the mail filtered as SPAM?  You need to do some debugging and narrow down *where* this process fails.

Comment: What debugging have you done to narrow down the problem?  A success message in AJAX means basically nothing as any request against the server, even one with fatal error, will return an HTTP 200 unless you specifically send an error header. Without an HTTP error response, your AJAX will think the request succeeded (because it did from the standpoint of the HTTP request/response handling)

Comment: You need to call `encodeURIComponent` on the values you're putting in `dataString`. Or pass an object and let jQuery encode it for you (my preference).

Comment: Can you use web inspector and see whether there are any traffic moving towards your server?